Inequality regarding the regularity of PDE
The screenshot is from Evans' PDE. I really cannot see how the following inequality (39) is establised. 
In my opinion, it should be
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|Du|^2 dx \Big|_{s=T} + \int_0^T\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u_t^2 + |D^2u|^2 dxdt \leq \left(\int_0^T \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f^2 dxdt + \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|Dg|^2 dx\right)
\end{align*}
How can it add a supremum in front of the first term? I don't think $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |Du|^2 dx$ is monotone in $t$.
Any helps or comments are appreciated!

In your inequality, replace $T$ by a $\tau$, you get an inequality that holds for any $0\le \tau\le T$. Take the sup of left side over $\tau$.

@Deane haha I see. Thanks!
